# Python: a list with an Element with "|", (and) operator

Tags: python, list, if-statement, contains

I have a function that analyse the transfer-text(buchungstext) of a bank transfer. Python looks if a word is contained in the transfer-text(buchungstext) then returns a GUID, the GUID is then the target booking account. But now I would like if in the list not only one word is searched, but two words are required with an AND-operation. It is important that the words can also be twisted in the sentence.

I've tried it like this before:   'LINEA'|'MADRID'

```
buchungstext = "METRO MADRID LINEA 7 MASTERCARD - MADRID " 


    # Tickets und Transport
    elif any(wort.upper() in buchungstext.upper() for wort in [  'LINEA'|'MADRID'   ,'METRO BARCELONA','METRO DE MADRID','LUFTHANSA','Trainline','SNCF TGV.COM','LIM*FAHRTKOSTEN','DB Reisezentrum','FINNAIR','DB Vertrieb GmbH','BOLT.EU','OEBB', 'DB BAHN A-NR','UBER','Flixbus','TIER','MVG RAD']):
        GUIDzwei = "d45xxxxxxxxxxxxxx013ab953ef26af2"
        return()



    # Hotels
    elif any(wort.upper() in buchungstext.upper() for wort in ['Hotel']):
        GUIDzwei = "d45xxxxxxxxxxxxxx013ab953ef26af2"
        return()

    # Mailservices, Post, DHL
    elif any(wort.upper() in buchungstext.upper() for wort in ['bpost','Deutsche Post','UPS','DHL']):
        GUIDzwei = "d45xxxxxxxxxxxxxx013ab953ef26af2"
        return()

# etc....
```

Comment: can you make an example of `buchungstext` input and output you want?

Comment: `buchungstext = "METRO MADRID LINEA 7 MASTERCARD - MADRID " `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change `in` to `re.search`.
Main question is how to search for existence of all provided words in any order. We can do that with [regex lookahead](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-regex-lookahead/)

```
r"(?=.*WORD1)(?=.*WORD2)"
```

So your crucial part could look like that:

```
any(re.search(wort, buchungstext, re.I | re.DOTALL) for wort in [r"(?=.*LINEA)(?=.*MADRIT)", "LUFTHANSA", "..."])
```

`I` flag is for ignore case search

`DOTALL` flag makes `.*` match newline as well

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, this may help.

You have a string (buchungstext) comprised of a number of whitespace delimited words.

You want to find out if **all** of a set of words exist in that string.

The search is not case sensitive.

Therefore:

```
buchungstext = "METRO MADRID LINEA 7 MASTERCARD - MADRID"

def check(sentence, words):
    # tokenise and convert to lowercase
    los = {w.lower() for w in sentence.split()}
    return all(k.lower() in los for k in words)

print(check(buchungstext, ['mastercard', 'metro']))
print(check(buchungstext, ['mastercard', 'munich']))
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
```

This gives a logical **AND** for the list passed as the second parameter. If you want logical **OR** just change *all* to *any*

Comment: I understood it that he wants list of list of words when outer list is OR and inner (where he used `|` to show that) is AND

Comment: @kosciej16 If my answer doesn't suit the OP's needs he can let me know and I'll delete it to avoid confusion